# Eigenvectors of a block Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I was wondering given the Hermitian matrix:
$$H =\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}$$
Are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$ at all related to the eigenvectors of $H$? In particular, I want to approximately find the eigenvector of H with the smallest eigenvalue through a variational algorithm (H is the hamiltonian for a quantum system and thus has a very large dimension), and I was wondering if there's any mathematical reasoning to be made as to why using the eigenvectors of block matrices would be a good heuristic.

I'm not looking for a proof or a definite formula (one likely doesn't exist) But rather any sort of relationship, or an intuitive reason as to whether or not the eigenvectors of A are any closer to the eigenvectors of H than a randomly chosen vector. (Here, by eigenvectors of A I mean the padded with $0$ version to fit the dimension e.g ($v1,...,v_n, 0_{n + 1},..0_{2n}$))

Comment: Is there any relation if $A=0$ and D=0$ ?

Comment: @BazyliZuczek No. However, I'm not looking for a proof or a definite formula (one likely doesn't exist) But rather any sort of relationship, or an intuitive reason as to whether or not the eigenvectors of A are any closer to the eigenvectors of H than a randomly chosen vector. (Here, by eigenvectors of A I mean padded with 0 version to fit the dimension e.g (v1,...$v_n$, 0,..0))

Comment: In my opiniom there is no relation whatsoever. Take $A=D=0$ and $B=C=B^*.$ Let $v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n$ be  the eigenvectors of $B.,$ Then $(v_k,\pm v_k)^t$  are the eigenvectors of $H.$

Comment: You might find the relationships described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) to be interesting